# Why BingMap heatMap doesn't show the correct location?

Tags: bing-maps

I was trying to show a location using heatMap module in bingMap. When I try to use some location heatMap show me diffrect location to that **long** and **lat**,

[HeatMap](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/defaultheatmap)

I just change the code like following way
`

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.HeatMap', function () {
    var mapDiv = map.getRootElement();
    
    var locations = [];
    
    locations.push(map.tryPixelToLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Point(28.150900,-81.468440), Microsoft.Maps.PixelReference.control));
    
    
    var heatMap = new Microsoft.Maps.HeatMapLayer(locations);
    map.layers.insert(heatMap);
});
```

This location is for **410 Marlberry Leaf Ave, Kissimmee, FL 34758, USA** but heatMap show me a location in ALESKA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are taking the lat/long coordinates and treating it as a pixel point and converting it into a location. This results in a completely different coordinate. Remove the call to `map.tryPixelToLocation(` and use the `Location` class instead of the `Point` class.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.HeatMap', function () {
    var mapDiv = map.getRootElement();
    
    var locations = [];
    
    locations.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(28.150900,-81.468440));
    
    
    var heatMap = new Microsoft.Maps.HeatMapLayer(locations);
    map.layers.insert(heatMap);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I got the idea as well as this is working